# Performing a breadth first search using a given class

Tags: python, class, graph

Using the following (very badly written) class:

```
class Graph:    
def __init__(self, graph_string):
    self.graph_string = []
    graph_string = graph_string.splitlines()
    for i in graph_string:
        i = (i.split())
        self.graph_string.append(i)
    directed_helper = self.graph_string[0]
    directed_score = directed_helper[0]
    weighted_helper = self.graph_string[0]
    weighted_score = weighted_helper[1]
    self.weighted = weighted_score
    self.directed = directed_score
    self.graph_string.pop(0)
    if self.directed == ("D"):
        self.directed = True
    elif self.directed == ("U"):
        self.directed = False
    if self.weighted == ("W"):
        self.weighted = True
    elif self.weighted != ("W"):
        self.weighted = False
    if self.weighted == False:
        self.edge_number = graph_string[0]
        self.edge_number = list(self.edge_number)
        self.edge_number = self.edge_number[2]
        self.edge_number = int(self.edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(self.edge_number)]  
    elif self.weighted == True:
        self.edge_number = graph_string[0]
        self.edge_number = list(self.edge_number)
        self.edge_number = self.edge_number[4]
        self.edge_number = int(self.edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(self.edge_number)]             
    if self.weighted == False:
        if self.directed == True:
            for s in self.graph_string:
                first_element = s[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = s[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, None))
        elif self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                first_element = t[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = t[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, None))
                self.adjacency_list[second_element].append((first_element, None))
    elif self.weighted == True:
        if self.directed == True:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                first_element = t[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = t[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                third_element = t[2]
                third_element = int(third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, third_element))
        if self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                first_element = t[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = t[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                third_element = t[2]
                third_element = int(third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, third_element))
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((first_element, third_element))
    (self.adjacency_list)
```

I wish to use the adjacency list it outputs given an inputted graph, to write a new function:

```
bfs_tree(graph, start)
```

which performs a breadth-first search which returns the parents array at the end of the search. 
For example for the input:

```
graph_string = """\
D 2
0 1
"""

print(bfs_tree(Graph(graph_string), 0))
```

The code should return:

```
[None, 0]
```

Or given:

```
    graph_string = """\
U 7
1 2
1 5
1 6
2 3
2 5
3 4
4 5
"""

print(bfs_tree(Graph(graph_string), 1))
```

The output should be:

```
[None, None, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1]
```

Any help would be appreciated :)